# Setting up Yesod DevelOpts

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm working on a Yesod project which includes some extensive database computations. The required calculation time may lead to the message "App not ready, please refresh" in development mode, followed by an automatic refresh. This in turn causes a restart of the database evaluation and prevents it from finishing.

This problem seems to be avoidable by increasing the DevelOpts proxyTimeout that is used in the function reverseProxy in Devel.hs (https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/master/yesod/Devel.hs). Changing the development options seems to be a quite common procedure. However, I haven't yet found a way to modify the default values in my Yesod project.

What is the usual way to set up the Yesod DevelOpts for a specific project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are set by command line parameters, run `yesod devel --help` for more information. In this case, you want to run with `-x`.

Comment: Looks like at least yesod version 1.8 is needed for this option to be present.